# How do I check if my nexus 7 is from 2012 or 2013?

Tags: nexus-7

I just received one as a gift and want to know if it is 2012 or 2013. How do I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has a rear facing camera along with a front facing camera, it's the 2013 version; else if it just has a (single) front facing camera it's 2012.

Simplest test.